# Is my router secure from remote hackers if it uses NAT and has its built-in firewall enabled?

Tags: networking, router, security, firewall

My router uses NAT, so it blocks unsolicited packets if I did not send a packet to the source of unsolicited packet first or my port is not forwarded. I understand that this is not meant to be a security measure, but it is still nice to have.

However, I have UPnP enabled, and some ports are forwarded (such as Skype). Since I do not want a remote hacker to cause damage, I set my router firewall to "medium".

Picture of the router firewall: http://support.moonpoint.com/network/routers/actiontec/MI424WR/Firewall_Settings.png

Am I secure from any inbound attacks a remote hacker might use?

(I understand having the router accept all outbound connections is a risk, but that is not the focus of my question)

Comment: Router software, like all other software, has many flaws.  In one test, [11 of 13 routers tested were hackable from the internet.](https://securityevaluators.com/knowledge/case_studies/routers/soho_router_hacks.php)  Reportedly, [the NSA finds it easier to hack routers than it does PCs.](http://www.wired.com/2013/09/nsa-router-hacking/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one can answer that question -- it depends if there are any bugs in the software on your router. You certainly can't *rely* on it being secure, as any software can have exploitable bugs. Using NAT gives you no protection against attacks aimed at the router itself, only against attacks aimed at your machine(s) behind the router.

Comment: But if the remote hacker does not want to hack the router for whatever reason, my machine(s) are still safe since my firewall blocks inbound connections, right?

Comment: No.  There are attacks that can get through a firewall.  An important one is [DNS cache poisoning.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_spoofing).

Comment: @John1024 Correct, but shouldn't the hacker have be in the same LAN as the victim for DNS cache poisoning?

Comment: @Raffat DNS cache poisoning can be done remotely.  As the wikipedia article states, firewalls that perform NAT not only don't stop it, they actually often defeat a PC's attempts at port randomness, thereby making DNS cache poisoning easier.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, there is no way to guarantee you are not going to be hacked, but it seem secure to me, as long as you do not allow any unidentified software to port forward. Also be aware that port forwarding Skype means more of a chance to be watched during a call.

Comment: Thank you, but wouldn't the firewall block any attempts to exploit software that does port forward?

Comment: It depends in the software

Comment: No, what I am saying is that my router firewall is configured to block all inbound connections (as you can see in the picture), so wouldn't that make it impossible to exploit port-forwarding software, such as Skype? I am not talking about my PC's firewall, rather the router firewall.

Comment: Firewalls cannot block everything, but yes.